# Gitlab unable to pull - trying to merge 3 versions into one

Tags: merge, gitlab

We are a team of 3.

We have 3 local versions of a project on Visual studio. We have not pushed those versions to gitlab yet.

How do we merge those 3 versions into one?

What we have tried so far is upload first project in gitlab. Then we clone back locally.  We deleted it. On its place  we have copied the second version of the project. We wanted to pull the first version in order to merge them but it says - project is up to date.

We don't want to do that by hand because it will take a long time, we would rather do it automatically. How do we do that?

Thanks in advance